# Solve a linear equation with PHP

Tags: php

The situation is:

GIVEN: 3 products units (quantity, fixed), per unit price range, interval of price change and total of 3 products price.

TARGET: Find out the unit prices of each product to match the total price at given quantity.

The following script I wrote in PHP, but it's showing "HTTP ERROR 500". What's the mistake I've done here, can you please advise me?

```
<?php

$qty1 = 1500000;
$qty2 = 300000;
$qty3 = 500;

$minRate = 125.000;
$maxRate = 160.000;

$gTotal = 255050000.000;

for ($i=$minRate; $i <= $maxRate; $i=$i+0.001) { 
    $item1Total = $i * $qty1;

    for ($j=$minRate; $j <= $maxRate; $j=$j+0.001) {
        $item2Total = $j * $qty2;
        $twoItemTotal = $item1Total + $item2Total;
        if ($twoItemTotal < $gTotal) {
            for ($k=$minRate; $k <= $maxRate; $k=$k+0.001) { 
                $item3Total = $j * $qty3;
                $allItemTotal = $twoItemTotal + $item3Total;
                if($allItemTotal == $gTotal){
                    echo $i . "<br>" . $j . "<br>" . $k;
                    echo "<br>-";
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `ini_set('display_errors','on');` at the beginning of the script to see where the actual error is?

Comment: I think you are hitting your memory limit or something.. You are looping 3x 35000 times....

Comment: This script needs a lot of time be executed, there's three nested loops each one gets iterated 35000 times, then the total iteration is: 35000^3 = 4.2875e+13, try to set the time limit to something else, but I don't recommend this, try to improve your code.

Comment: If we can have the algorithm then we can help you with a fast way to do this task.

Comment: @Karkouch, thanks and you're right, it's huge loop to go. 
The conditions for this task to find out the unit price list is- the unit price must have 3 decimal points (not truncate ether, e.g. NOT 0.926544 to 0.927 or 0.926!) and last digit of 3 decimals cannot be 0 (e.g. NOT 0.980 or 0.230).
Finally, the task is find out the unit price, X, Y, Z which will satisfy the equation:
1500000*X + 3300000*Y + 500*Z = 255050000.000
Please let me know if you have any more. Thanks.

Comment: So, in other words, the problem is: Find X, Y and Z which will satisfy the equation 1500000*X + 3300000*Y + 500*Z = 255050000.000 and all of them must be in this interval [125, 160].

Comment: Yes, you are right! @Karkouch

Answer (score 0):

(I tried using Latex here on stackoverflow but it's not working!)

So the problem is:

> Find X, Y and Y which satisfy the equation 1500000*X + 3300000*Y + 500*Z = 255050000.000, and X, Y and Z must be in this interval [ 125.000, 160.000 ]?

So let X and Y be any number in [ 125.000, 160.000 ],and find Z?

Using simple math we find:

Z = ( 255050000.000 - 3300000*Y - 1500000*X )/500

Z should be greater than or equal 125.000, and less than or equal 160.000.

Which mean:

125.000 ≤ ( 255050000.000 - 3300000*Y - 1500000*X )/500 ≤ 160.000

Then

( 255050000.000 - 500*160.000 - 1500000*X )/3300000 ≤ Y ≤ ( 255050000.000 - 500*125.000 - 1500000*X )/3300000

let Ymin = ( 255050000.000 - 500*160.000 - 1500000*X )/3300000

and Ymax = ( 255050000.000 - 500*125.000 - 1500000*X )/3300000

Y too should be greater than or equal 125.000, and less than or equal 160.000

So Ymin ≥ 125.000 and Ymax ≤ 160.000

```
<?php
$qty1 = 1500000;
$qty2 = 300000;
$qty3 = 500;
$minRate = 125.000;
$maxRate = 160.000;
$gTotal = 255050000.000;
$solutions = array();
$N = 0;
$t_start = microtime(true);
for( $i = $minRate; $i <= $maxRate; $i += 0.001 ){
    $j_min = ( $gTotal - $qty3 * $maxRate - $i * $qty1 ) / $qty2;
    $j_max = ( $gTotal - $qty3 * $minRate - $i * $qty1 ) / $qty2;

    if( $j_min < $minRate || $j_max > $maxRate ) continue;

    for( $j = $j_min; $j <= $j_max; $j += 0.001 ){
        //
        $k = ( $gTotal - $j * $qty2 - $i * $qty1 ) / $qty3;
        $solutions[] = [ 'i'=>$i, 'j'=>$j, 'k'=>$k ];
        $N++;
        if( !($N % 10000) ){
            // Write into a csv file then reset, (because of memory limit)
            $solutions = array();
        }
    }
}
printf( '%d solutions found after %f seconds%s', $N, (microtime(true) - $t_start), PHP_EOL );
```

I have run this script on my laptop and this is what I get: `412292 solutions found after 0.166070 seconds`

If you want high precision results then try [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Karkouch for your efforts. I'll try an I'll let you know!!!!